# Taking count from two different tables and merge two results into one

Tags: sql

I am trying to take `count(*)` from two different tables and merge the result into one.

The query I am writing is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS a FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS b FROM table_b;
```

But this is only returning the result with count of the first query.

I want the result to be like this

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 12 |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you can use sub query for second column as below

```
select count(*) as a, (select count(*) as b from table_b) from table_a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just select the result of two derived tables,

```
select 
 (select count(*) from table_a) a,
 (select count(*) from table_b) b;
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: What about the above is not standard ansi sql?
The syntax is valid in pretty much all RDBMS.

Comment: Missing <from clause>. (Oracle users would typically add `FROM DUAL` at the end.)

Comment: @jarlh there is no missing clause, Oracle of course may have its own non-standard requirements (no one mentioned Oracle however) the syntax works fine for at least the following [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n3XTIOaq)
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DuR1cSNh)
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6w3Bbyt_)
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QIDvQjCk)
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yYW6zapa)
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UulFK4F_) so is definitely *not* product specific.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), 7.16 <query specification>: `SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>`, 7.4 <table expression>: `<table expression> ::=
<from clause>
[ <where clause> ]
[ <group by clause> ]
[ <having clause> ]
[ <window clause> ]`, i.e. <from clause> is not optional.

Comment: No basically that means you don't need a from clause to select an expression, the subquery is a table expression; In ANSI/ISO SQL, the FROM clause is not strictly necessary if you're only selecting literal values or expressions that don't require data from tables, as shown by at least 6 different platforms above.

Comment: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ says _syntax error: ;
expected:
correction: FROM <identifier> ;_

Answer (score 0):

```
select z.a,x.b
from
(
  select count(*) as a from table_a
)z
cross join
(
   select count(*) as b from table_b
)x
```

Comment: I get syntax error here. (You need _derived tables_.)

Comment: getting syntax error with the cross join

Comment: amended based on the first comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is

```
Select a.cnt+ b.cnt1 from (SELECT Count(*) as cnt from table_a) as a 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cnt1 from table_b) as b;
```